# Anchor Helper in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, html-helper

I have already rendered succesfully a navigation menu using zf2 navigation helper.
I've found link href helper.

But I can't find a helper to write:

```
<a href="http:\\wwww.example.com">Example</a>
```

Is there such helper in zf2?

Comment: Question: Why do you need a HELPER to write a simple link that is outside of the scope of your Module? Just because there's a Framework behind the page doesn't mean people should forget about basic HTML and PHP ^^ Of course though you are always free to write yourself a helper like `$this->simpleUrl('http://google.com', 'Google');` (which of course would result in MORE UNNECESSARY Overhead and more code, too)

Comment: ok, ok calm down. it's just a question. ofcourse i will not create a helper for that. i just want to follow zf2 rules in my project because i still learning it.

Comment: No worries, im calm. Just mentioned this because there's lots of people simply forgetting about the simple stuff, just because they start working with a framework ;) No offense intended :)